# Infinte scroll with FlutterMap

Tags: flutter, mapbox, mapbox-gl, fluttermap

I am implementing Flutter Map package in my project. The only thing I need now is to make the map move 360 view. Is it possible to do this with this package?

Answer (score -1):

@Abhinav it is possible to implement a 360-degree view in Flutter using the `flutter_map` package. To achieve this, you'll need to use a plugin or extension that supports 360-degree imagery or panoramas. A popular plugin that can help you achieve this effect is the `flutter_map_panorama` package.